# How to force chrome webdriver to use a script cached of the drive in new sessions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, caching, webdriver

I want to utilize a JavaScript script stored in the cache folder instead of re-downloading it in each new session. I do not wish to interrupt the fetching of scripts from the server. The script has a long expiry date (one year), as indicated in the response header.
I am using Selenium and Seleniumwire libraries in Python.

Or maybe it is impossible and I have to keep session for, say, a week, without ever quitting webdriver?

Any ideas? :-)

I have attempted various configuration options, including intercepting requests and renaming the script in the interceptor, but I have been unable to compel the browser driver to simply reuse the script. Instead, it repeatedly downloads and saves the same version with a new name, as shown in this cache folder view."[cache folder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dvhX.png) 
I send cookies to login first.
Chrome WebDriver version: 120.0.6099.109

`chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=./01profile")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') ``

Comment: I believe Seleniumwire makes it's own requests.  (it's sort of in parallel...)  Try without that and see if it helps.

Comment: It works as you say, but I needed Seleniumwire to apply specific seleniumiwre options to authenticate to proxy - plain selenium seems not to have that possibility. However thank you very much :-)